# Why does Lightroom not have a cyan-red slider for color correction?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, photo-editing, color, color-correction

They have color correction sliders for yellow-blue and green-magenta but not for red-cyan, unlike in Photoshop. It is really annoying to go into Photoshop when I need to make those simple adjustments -- does anyone know a reason this isn't included in Lightroom?

Comment: Because it's set for the primary two camera-centric adjustments: temperature and tint.

Comment: Don't close this: [Kai's answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/114199/4141) shows that there is a mathematically-correct answer to it. The OP may have the opinion that Adobe doesn't understand color, but that doesn't mean the correct answer is also opinion-based.

Comment: You can get the same results as a cyan ←→ red slider by using both the blue ←→ yellow and green ←→ magenta sliders together.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at any color wheel, you have two axes on the wheel:

[image: color wheel]

To correct any color cast, this is usually enough. You can correct the main source of color shift in natural light on the temp axis (blue/yellow), and then do the fine tuning on the tint axis (magenta/green). Tint most often occurs through artificial light.

```
         magenta
  red      |
        x--|
        |  |
yellow ----+---- blue
           |
           |
           |     cyan
         green
```

The axis you propose is actually 45° off these axes, you could also correct any cast in this direction by using the other 2. However, this also explains why there is no 3rd slider: using it would always affect the temp & tint as well, although it would be easier with it to correct such a color cast.